# How to backup a whole wordpress site?

Tags: backup, wordpress

How to backup a whole wordpress site from ubuntu?

There is a program like WinSCP to use it for backup, or it is not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can use Filezilla (available through the Software Centre, or by runnin to connect to SFTP servers, in the same manner as WinSCP.

This will only backup the files (including uploads, attachments, themes), in order to create a complete backup you will either want to make a database backup, or use WordPress's built-in backup feature.

The built-in feature will backup all "posts, pages, comments, custom fields, terms, navigation menus and custom posts" and can be accessed by navigating to Tools > Export in the administration panel.

Answer (score 3):

In the wordpress admin console, go to tools -> export -> download export file.

Alternatively dump the DB to mysqldump & tar up your wordpress directory.

Comment: I use mysqldump and it is a good tool. Do you thing this is the best way to keep backup my WordPress? (I know it is a DB backup tool)

Comment: @Vassilis You still need to backup the wordpress folder to save any uploads such as pictures.

Answer (score 1):

[Shell script to backup WordPress.com site](https://github.com/l0b0/export/blob/master/WordPress.com.sh). If your WP site is not on wordpress.com it should be easy to adapt the script. That way you can easily do a nightly backup including files automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can utilize Filezilla for backing up your files.  For further detail procedures, you may refer to [Install WordPress on Ubuntu](http://networkstatic.net/install-wordpress-on-ubuntu/).  There are several [backup WordPress plugins](http://awesome4wp.com/backupbuddy-v5-1-0-7-back-up-restore-and-move-wordpress-plugin/) available over the Internet, you can find the most suitable one for conducting this procedure.